# Struggling with building up the top part of a test site

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Very new to coding, I am really struggling to centre my banner and have the two logos for facebook and twitter hanging to the right of the centered image using bootstrap. I have put an image what kind of thing I am after, and did not really want to do it with padding.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/agC3r.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"         href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">     </script>

 <title>Shrewsbury admag</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
.banner {
width : 300px;
height : 100px;
}
.facebook_logo {
width : 45px;
height : 45px;
}
.twitter_logo {
width : 45px;
height : 45px;
}
.top_area{
float :left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

        <div class='row text-center'>

        <img class="banner" src="logo.jpg" alt="Shrewsbury admag">


            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Shrewsbury-Admag/451886594847965">
                <img class="facebook_logo" src="facebook.jpeg" alt="Find us on facebook">
            </a>

            <a href="https://twitter.com/shrewsburyadmag">
                <img class="twitter_logo" src="Twitterlogo.png" alt="Follow us on twitter" align="bottom">
            </a>

    </div>

</body>
```

Ignore my terrible spacing

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place your Facebook/Twitter icons in a column, I'll suggest to put these both icons (links) in a `div` (let's give it class `social-holder`) and apply the following css:

```
.social-holder {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
.social-holder a {display: block;}

<div class="social-holder">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Shrewsbury-Admag/451886594847965">
        <img class="facebook_logo" src="facebook.jpeg" alt="Find us on facebook">
    </a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/shrewsburyadmag">
        <img class="twitter_logo" src="Twitterlogo.png" alt="Follow us on twitter" align="bottom">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that has done the trick, would you mind explaining the display inline-block and display block, as far as I can tell that has solved it. (I had tried putting them in a div before but it did not quite work).

Comment: `display:inline-block;` will make the div stay inline as like it is a span/link or a bit of plain text. `display:block;` for links will place them one under another, as we don't wont them stay in one line